# Put div in the right side of browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following **HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

and **CSS**:

```
#wrapper{
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #d;
  float:right;
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width: 100px;

  background-color:black;
}
```

what I actually want is this but on the right side of the screen (should work "flawlessly") and as a bonus if you will "fade" the part inside (probably background-color:white?) and give a black glow effect to the right border of that div. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/58ajr/1/

```
#wrapper{
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #d;
  position:fixed;
  right: 0;
  height:100%;
  width: 100px;

  background-color:black;
}
```

remove `float: right`, add `right: 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
float:right
```

with

```
right:0
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ph75L/5/)

Hoe it helps

Leo

Answer (score 0):

```
you can also specify the number of pixels you want to move to right using margin-left

 <style type="text/css">
    .class1
    {
        margin-left : 600px;
        background-color: #CCFFFF;
         height: 236px; 
         width: 336px;
        }
    </style> 

<div class="class1">

This is 600 px away
    </div>
```